# How to deploy a split back-to-back topology?

Tags: topology, dmz

We want to install SharePoint Foundation 2010 to our customer.
They have 3 WFEs on DMZ and 1 SQL on intranet.
They have AD on intranet.

How do you do this?

Comment: What kind of authenticaiton method do you plan to use for SharePoint?

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint Stack Exchange! Please read [our editing guidelines](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115/have-any-tips-for-editing-questions/116#116) which I've used to improve your question. These help more people to find your post, and also encourage more to answer it. See [ask] for more general guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at:

1. [Planning and architecture for SharePoint Server 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261834.aspx)
2. [Technical diagrams (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263199.aspx)
3. [Plan for server farms and environments (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc789337.aspx)